# Validate a date received in String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When the request is made by Postman, I need to check if the received date is valid in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format and then send it to my Service. Is there any way to do this with String?

Example:

My Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/by-date")
public ResponseEntity<List<ResponseRet>> getByDate(@RequestParam(required = false) String dateGte,
                                                              @RequestParam(required = false) String dateLte) {
    List<ResponseRet> responseRet = searchService.findByDate(dateGte, dateLte);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseRet);
}
```

In this case I would need to do this check in the Controller or in the Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service class you can try to parse `String` into `LocalDate`:

```
public List<ResponseRet> findByDate(String dateGte, String dateLte) {
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(dateGte);
        LocalDate.parse(dateLte);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        // log, throw your custom exception with 400 http response code or whatever
    }
    // other code;
}
```

While parsing, `LocalDate` is using default `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` - dates like "2022-08-24".
If you want to parse with other format, create instance of `DateTimeFormatter` and use it:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/mm/dd");
LocalDate.parse(dateGte, formatter);
```

Also you can change your method's arguments type to `LocalDate` and do validation on the controller level:

```
@GetMapping("/by-date")
public ResponseEntity<List<ResponseRet>> getByDate(
                       @RequestParam(required = false) @Valid @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate dateGte,
                       @RequestParam(required = false) @Valid @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate dateLte) {
    List<ResponseRet> responseRet = searchService.findByDate(dateGte.toString(), dateLte.toString());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseRet);
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well in my question, my goal is to work with this String and check if it's in the default date "yyyy-mm-dd" without having to transform it into LocalDate, I need it to be in String because the other API consumes the date in String.

Comment: @RodrigoM as you can see in the first example I'm not suggesting to save `LocalDate` anywhere or to pass it to other API, I just use its 'parse(CharSequence)` method to check if your String *can be represented* as a valid date, because if not - it will throw an exception.

Comment: @RodrigoM also in the second example I'm only suggesting to change controller method's arguments to `LocalDate` for purposes of earlier validation, but I'm passing `String` values to your `SearchService` by using `LocalDate.toString()`, which converts by default to "yyyy-mm-dd" format